# Including a PHP file, treats relative URLs from that directory

Tags: php, url, relative-path, server-side-scripting

I have a PHP file at my server **root**.. index.php .. which [`include`](http://www.php.net/include/)'s .. DIR/main.php

Now .. DIR/main.php ..  [`include`](http://www.php.net/include/)'s many **nearby** PHP files using **relative** URLs using .. `include("./common1.php");`

Any way I can change the relative-URL **base path** so when including "DIR/main.php" It can relatively access its nearby PHP files like "DIR/common1.php", instead of trying to find "common1.php" at the site root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the *"relative-URL **base path**"* to your directory

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . '/DIR' );
```

Second, include your file!

```
require( 'main.php' );
```

That should work though I've not tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [set_include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Edit: When appending paths to [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) be sure to use the PATH_SEPARATOR constant as it is intended to make your include path OS agnostic.

```
<?php

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    get_include_path(),
    '/DIR1',
    '/DIR2/DIR3',
    dirname(__FILE__),
)));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to lonut's answer, you can get the directory of the file using a combination of the [`__FILE__`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant and `dirname()`.

```
$include_path = dirname(__FILE__);
set_include_path($include_path);
```